# eliminar el script pero internamente se sigue ejecutando

Tags: javascript

estoy utilizando grapes para crear formularios, el problema es que todos tienen la libreria diferente, tengo adjuntado el tipo de formulario a adjuntar en un select, cuando selecciono el tipo de formulario me debe cargar el div con su respectivo script que contiene lo de la libreria, el problema radica en que al seleccionar un tipo de formulario, me cambia el contenido, crea el script y todo, cuando selecciono otro, supuestamente se eliminar el script anterior, pero no es asi, parece como si internamente se siguiera ejecutando y me esta generando error

tengo mi select de esta forma

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            <select id="listtipoformulario" class="form-select"><option value="0">Select Form</option><option value="Informed Consents">Informed Consents</option><option value="Results">Results</option><option value="Attachments">Attachments</option><option value="Clinical Histories">Clinical Histories</option></select>
            <label for="listtipoformulario">Type Form</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

el js que obtiene el cambio lo tengo de esta forma

```
$("#listtipoformulario").on("change", function(){
    eliminarscript($('#seleccionanterior').val());
    //$('#contenidograpesgeneral').empty();
    $('#title-users').empty();
    $('#seleccionanterior').val($("#listtipoformulario").val());
    if(($(this).val() == 'Clinical Histories') == true){
        var div =   '<div id="divcontenedorhistoriaclinica"><div id="editor"></div></div>';
        $('#title-users').append('Medical History Form');
        $('#contenidograpesgeneral').append(div);
        var script = document.createElement( "script" );
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = 'recursos/GrapesJS/js/main.js';
        script.onload = function () {
           // el script se ha cargado 
        };
        document.getElementById('divcontenedorhistoriaclinica').appendChild(script)
    }else{
        $('#contenidograpesgeneral').empty();
        $('#title-users').append('Forms');
    }
});
```

y esta es mi funcion que eliminar el script

```
function eliminarscript(eleccion){
    if((eleccion == 'Clinical Histories') == true){
        var segundo_p = document.getElementById('divcontenedorhistoriaclinica');
        document.getElementById('contenidograpesgeneral').removeChild(segundo_p);
    }
}
```

si yo inspecciono los elementos, ya no me sale el script, pero resulta que si vuelvo a seleccionar el formulario de historia clinica, me dice que se esta ejecutando dos veces el script, no tengo mas ideas, porfa muchas gracias